# Swift - Creating shadow with 2 different colours for imageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, shadow

I'm wondering how to create a shadow with two different colours for an imageView. For example the top and left side has a different colour than the right and bottom side of the imageView.

Comment: you need to implement custom shadow ...

Comment: Do you want an ***upper-left shadow*** and a ***lower-right shadow*** like this: https://imgur.com/a/cdiYOc8 ? Or do you want a single shadow that is a gradient from top-left to bottom-right?

Comment: @DonMag Hey! Yeah i want exactly like that image you linked to. Do you know how i can achieve that or know a guide i can read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get different color shadows - one going up-left and one going down-right - on a `UIImageView`, one approach would be:

- Subclass `UIView`
- Give it 3 `CALayer` sublayers

  - Shadow 1 layer
  - Shadow 2 layer
  - Image layer

This also makes it easy to add rounded corners.

Here is a sample class. It has `@IBInspectable` properties to set the image, corner radius, shadow colors and shadow offsets. It is also marked `@IBDesignable` so you can see how it looks while designing in Storyboard / Interface Builder:

```
@IBDesignable
class DoubleShadowRoundedImageView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage? = nil {
        didSet {
            imageLayer.contents = image?.cgImage
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0

    @IBInspectable var shad1X: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var shad1Y: CGFloat = 0.0

    @IBInspectable var shad2X: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var shad2Y: CGFloat = 0.0

    @IBInspectable var shad1Color: UIColor = UIColor.blue
    @IBInspectable var shad2Color: UIColor = UIColor.red

    var imageLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
    var shadowLayer1: CALayer = CALayer()
    var shadowLayer2: CALayer = CALayer()

    var shape: UIBezierPath {
        return UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    }

    var shapeAsPath: CGPath {
        return shape.cgPath
    }

    var shapeAsMask: CAShapeLayer {
        let s = CAShapeLayer()
        s.path = shapeAsPath
        return s
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        clipsToBounds = false
        backgroundColor = .clear

        self.layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer1)
        self.layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer2)
        self.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)

        imageLayer.frame = bounds

        imageLayer.mask = shapeAsMask

        shadowLayer1.frame = bounds
        shadowLayer2.frame = bounds

        shadowLayer1.shadowPath = (image == nil) ? nil : shapeAsPath
        shadowLayer1.shadowOpacity = 0.80

        shadowLayer2.shadowPath = (image == nil) ? nil : shapeAsPath
        shadowLayer2.shadowOpacity = 0.80

        shadowLayer1.shadowColor = shad1Color.cgColor
        shadowLayer2.shadowColor = shad2Color.cgColor

        shadowLayer1.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shad1X, height: shad1Y)
        shadowLayer2.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shad2X, height: shad2Y)

    }
}
```

You would probably want to change some of the default values, and you might want to add some additional properties (such as shadow opacity).

Example results:

[image]

Comment: This is really great thanks. Just being curious, how expensive is this task? Say if this is used for a collection view or table view?